# Laravel - Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I am trying to save form details into my database, through a controller. When I click submit, I am shown this error:

> in ClinicController.php line 58 at
>   ClinicController->store(object(Request))

Line 58 (See below for the entire function) is:

```
$request->user()->create([
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $request->user()->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);

    $request->user()->clinic()->create([
        'clinic_name' => $request->clinic_name,
        'telephone' => $request->telephone,
        'address_1' => $request->address_1,
        'address_2' => $request->address_2,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'postcode' => $request->postcode
    ]);

    return redirect('/home');

}
```

**User Model:**

```
public function clinic() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Clinic::class);
}
```

**Clinic Model:**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Routes.php:**

```
Route::post('/clinic', 'ClinicController@store');
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: I was following Laravel's example on their website - it appears to be a valid way of adding data through a controller - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#introduction.

Comment: If you are getting a trying to call method on null, then `$request->user()` is returning null, which means no logged in user, or missing web middleware perhaps.  @chasenyc, yes `$request->user()` is a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the currently authorized user, just use `app()->user()`. Also, you can simplify a lot of your logic and make it much easier to read.

```
auth()
->user()
->create($request->only([
    'name', 
    'email', 
    'password'
]))
->clinic()
->create($request->only([
    'clinic_name', 
    'telephone', 
    'address_1', 
    'address_2', 
    'city', 
    'postcode'
]));

return redirect('/home');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your example removes my user()->clinic() which in Laravel's own example, automatically adds the foreign key. How can I do that in your example please?

Comment: @Ben Hi Ben! It doesn't remove it, it in fact will chain it from the `app()->user()->create()` as the `create()` method will return an instance of the new `Model`. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy, that was very handy! I've never seen this way of adding in Laravel before. Very informative. Upon adding your code, I am now presented with this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::user()`. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: @Ben That's interesting that it would error out on the `user()` from the IoC instance. Can you instead do `Auth::user()`? Make sure you `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: The Application doesn't have a `user` method, perhaps you meant `auth()->user()`

Comment: @lagbox Good catch.

Comment: np ... it resolves the same user as  `$request->user()` does

Comment: @lagbox and Ohgodwhy, thank you both for your help. This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = App\User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);

    $clinic = App\Clinic::create([
        'clinic_name' => $request->clinic_name,
        'telephone' => $request->telephone,
        'address_1' => $request->address_1,
        'address_2' => $request->address_2,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'postcode' => $request->postcode
    ])

    $user->clinics()->attach($clinic->id);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    App\User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);

    App\Clinic::create([
        'clinic_name' => $request->clinic_name,
        'telephone' => $request->telephone,
        'address_1' => $request->address_1,
        'address_2' => $request->address_2,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'postcode' => $request->postcode
    ]);

    return redirect('/home');

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was actually following Laravel's own example - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#introduction - and by using: `user()->clinic()->create`, it was mentioned that it would handle the foreign key implementation. How can I achieve this with your method? Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at @Ohgodwhy answer

Answer (score 0):

I think problems with $fillable property, make sure to check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = App\User::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => $request->password
]);

$user->clinic()->create([
    'clinic_name' => $request->clinic_name,
    'telephone' => $request->telephone,
    'address_1' => $request->address_1,
    'address_2' => $request->address_2,
    'city' => $request->city,
    'postcode' => $request->postcode
]);

return redirect('/home');
```